# When editing a user's info should the save button save only or save and return to address book?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, save, edit

I am creating a design for an address book in a software application. To create a new user it directs you to a new page to fill out the user's information. Should the save at the bottom of the page save and display a success message? Or, save and return to the address book with a save alert message displayed at top?

I am unsure of the best solution to direct the user to after they save a user's info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save and return to address book but need to acknowledge the user with successfull message

We need to keep the Address book as landing page for all the actions like edit, delete and share functionalities. So that's the reason to return Address book page after saving data. This process is standard on around 90% of the application.

When user return to Address book page, feel in command with the page cos user has multiple actions on this page.

Comment: could you expand on your answer